# How to properly use CF7 hooks

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I'm fairly new to Wordpress development so please excuse if my question is dumb.

I'm trying to call a REST API when CF7 is submitted. So I've tried to hook into both wpcf7_before_send_mail and wpcf7_mail_sent but to no avail. Whenever I put this code in my theme's functions.php file; the form doesn't submit and keeps on loading (like it's trying to submit)

For simplicity's sake, I tried to do a simple redirect as you see in the following code but that's not working either. The form works when I remove the following code from functions.php file.

```
add_action("wpcf7_mail_sent", "wpcf7_do_something_else");  
function wpcf7_do_something_else($cf7) {
    wp_redirct('https://google.com');
}
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It keeps loading because it's an ajax function and you are trying to use 'wp_redirect' in it and that won't work.

The 'wpcf7_mail_sent' hook is working fine, you can test that by using something like that

```
add_action("wpcf7_mail_sent", "wpcf7_do_something_else");  
function wpcf7_do_something_else($cf7) {
    var_dump($cf7);exit;
}
```

And while sending the form monitor the 'network' tab in the dev tools of your browser to see the results and you will find that it returns an object of the submitted data.